# Is it possible to set table names non case sensitive for particular MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have created all store procedures, functions and tables name without care of case sensitivity as my development environment is  Windows.

Now My client's production server is on LINUX and there are so many MySQL database hosted on same server. So setting `lower_case_table_names = 1` in `my.cnf` will change setting for all other database and that my client doesn't want to do.

Now how can I set `lower_case_table_names = 1` for just my database?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do this

Comment: I hope I can Otherwise I need to check all my store procedure codes and queries and set table name manually..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can configure how tables names are stored on the disk using the system variable lower_case_table_names.

Read the section: 10.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html  for more information

Comment: .How to set  lower_case_table_names =1 for particular database?